# Why does Gringo reveals the location of remaining money to Caracas?

Tags: plot-explanation, get-the-gringo

In *Get The Gringo (2012)*, Gringo was caught by robbing $4 million from Frank, but Cops took some amount of money for themselves and arrested gringo on false charges.

In Prison, after receiving a phone call from Embassy Guy about money or something, he left in the middle of the call and told Caracas the whereabouts of the remaining money.

**Why did Gringo leaked the details of remaining money to Caracas?**